# Changing the background color with click using queryselector (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written this code for these buttons, so when I click on them, the background color changes, but it doesn't work. what seems to be the problem?

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>JavaScript Background Color Switcher</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
        <span  class="button" id="grey"></span>
        <span  class="button" id="white"></span>
        <span  class="button" id="blue"></span>
        <span  class="button" id="yellow"></span>
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>   
</body>
</html> 

JS File:
document.querySelector('.button').addEventListener('click', function btn (id) {
  document.body.style.background = id
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code:

1) `document.querySelector` will only return the *first* matching element

2) the `click` event does not take a function with such arguments.

Better code would be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.button')
  .forEach(btn => 
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => document.body.style.background = btn.id)
  );
```

(here I reuse `btn` again instead of using the data from the event because I already know which button you hit, so no need to mess around with `ev.target...`

Answer (score 1):

You must use `.querySelectorAll` to add a listener on all the `.button` elements.

I also corrected the syntax for your `addEventListener`

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.button')
btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    document.body.style.background = evt.target.id
  })
})
```

```css
.button { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<div class="canvas">
  <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
  <span class="button" id="grey">Grey</span>
  <span class="button" id="white">White</span>
  <span class="button" id="blue">Blue</span>
  <span class="button" id="yellow">Yellow</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use document.querySelectorAll instead document.querySelector

```js
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.button')

buttons.forEach(element=>{
element.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  document.body.style.background = e.target.id
  })
})
```

```css
span{
padding: 4px 6px;
border: 1px solid;
cursor: pointer;
}
#grey{
background :grey;
}

#white{
background :white;
}

#blue{
background :blue;
}

#yellow{
background :yellow;
}
```

```html
    <div class="canvas">
        <h1>Color Scheme Switcher</h1>
        <span  class="button" id="grey">gray</span>
        <span  class="button" id="white">white</span>
        <span  class="button" id="blue">blue</span>
        <span  class="button" id="yellow">yellow</span>
    </div>
```

You can